# How to import libraries in processing.js?

Tags: processing.js

I'm trying to import the library processing.video.*, but it looks like it doesn't recoginize it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really talking about Processing.js, then you can't import Java libraries.

But this looks like regular Processing, not Processing.js. In which case, you need to add the library to your sketch using the `Sketch` menu.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on using libraries in Processing available [here](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries).